# ElasticSearch : GeoLocation distance search across types

Tags: search, elasticsearch, geolocation

As shown below, there are two types in my **city** index - **zoo** and **hotel**. How do I find all zoos having a hotel in 1KM radius? Here is the mapping of my index :

```
GET /city/_mapping
{
   "city": {
      "mappings": {
         "hotel": {
            "properties": {
               "location": {
                  "type": "geo_point"
               },
               "name": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         },
         "zoo": {
            "properties": {
               "location": {
                  "type": "geo_point"
               },
               "name": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a [geo-distance filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-filter.html) for the whole index (just don't specify a type).

As I quick test I created an index like this:

```
PUT /test_index/
{
   "mappings": {
      "hotel": {
         "properties": {
            "location": {
               "type": "geo_point"
            },
            "name": {
               "type": "string"
            }
         }
      },
      "zoo": {
         "properties": {
            "location": {
               "type": "geo_point"
            },
            "name": {
               "type": "string"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Added a couple of documents

```
POST /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_type":"hotel","_id":1}}
{"name":"hotel1","location":{"lat" : 40.001, "lon" : -70.001}}
{"index":{"_type":"zoo","_id":1}}
{"name":"zoo1","location":{"lat" : 40.002, "lon" : -70.002}}
```

And then I can search like this. This query returns the one document:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "geo_distance": {
               "distance": 200,
               "distance_unit": "km",
               "location": {
                  "lat": 40,
                  "lon": -70
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "hotel",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "name": "hotel1",
               "location": {
                  "lat": 40.001,
                  "lon": -70.001
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

And this query returns both:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "geo_distance": {
               "distance": 300,
               "distance_unit": "km",
               "location": {
                  "lat": 40,
                  "lon": -70
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 5,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "hotel",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "name": "hotel1",
               "location": {
                  "lat": 40.001,
                  "lon": -70.001
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "zoo",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "name": "zoo1",
               "location": {
                  "lat": 40.002,
                  "lon": -70.002
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here's the code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/948d23a5327cf5f22dd368146f37d09e30765fee

Comment: What I want is - find all the zoos having a hotel in 1 km radius. What you have done is - find all the hotels and zoos within a radius from a given lat,long.

Comment: Ah, damn, you're right. Apologies, I didn't read the question closely enough. I don't think you can do anything quite that elaborate with just Elasticsearch. You'll probably have to write some code to loop through zoos and pick the ones that have a close hotel (you can do that last bit with what I posted, of course).